# Do Something When href is Clicked

Tags: java, html, swing, jeditorpane

So, I have a `JEditorPane` with a bunch of text, and I want to be able to click on some the text enclosed in a tag, and have it activate some function, similar to the `onclick` in JavaScript with HTML. I've tried doing this with `href`s and `<a>` tags, but as I was not going to a website, it didn't work out for me.

So, how can I click on text enclosed in a tag in a `JEditorPane` and then do something accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You want `JEditorPane.addHyperlinkListener` to handle to event and load the relevant page or perform another action.